# Avoiding invalid data statements on conversion to numeric

Tags: sas

I have a large table with several variables which will be input to a statistical analysis. As a statistician, I prefer all factors to be numeric, so that they work predictably in regression models, with formats to show labels for numeric values, e.g. race, sex.

when I `set` the original data, I rename all the character variables that I want to recode to add a suffix of `c` (for character values). I then use an `input` statement for each of them, with the corresponding `best1.` or `best8.` or appropriate format.

The problem is that the log becomes cluttered when missing variables are coded as actually missing values, eg  `.`. I could add a line of `if not missing(varc) then var =  input(varc, best8.);` for each variable, but this seems inefficient and hard to read.

Is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're okay with eliminating the missing values message entirely (including things that 'could' be an issue) you can prepend `??` to the informat to tell it to not give you that warning.

```
var=input(varc,??8.);
```

Comment: Beautiful. That is convenient, elegant, and efficient. Before, SAS spitting out the warning consumed just as much CPU time as reading the record itself. Switching to this format halved the processing time. (I have a very large dataset).

Answer (score 1):

Create a format like this and use it instead of `best8.`.

```
proc format library=work;
    invalue myform
    '' = .
    other=best8.
    ;
run;
options fmtsearch=(work);
```

Comment: (+1) This is a good response and indeed I have a separate SAS file with hundreds of formats, so what harm is one more? I do prefer Joe's answer however because it uses an existing format.

Comment: Thanks!  As Joe points out, his solution suppresses messages besides those caused by missing values.  My method should get rid of the missing value messages, but still warn on other types of problems.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to use

```
PROC STDIZE .. 
REPONLY MISSING=0;
RUN;
```

Comment: STDIZE would not help. The variables are character and I want them to be numeric and not change their coded levels.